# Stop TextEdit from using iCloud save

Tags: macos, icloud, textedit

Every time I save a TextEdit file 'SAVE' always goes to iCloud, even though I have been saving to another folder. Can I stop 'SAVE' from doing this?

I run OS X 10.9.4

Answer (score 11):

Saving to cloud is easy to disable in system preferences:

1. Go to the iCloud Preference Pane
2. Select iCloud Drive
3. Click on "**Options**"
4. Check and uncheck the apps you want saved in iCloud.

This was tested on Yosemite and a Macbook Pro 2015

Comment: TextEdit was taking forever to open on my machine, and unchecking the box for TextEdit solved the problem.

Comment: Worked reliable on macOS 11 Big Sur!

Henceforth unsaved documents get auto-saved to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Autosave Information/` as `Unsaved TextEdit Document.txt` , `Unsaved TextEdit Document 2.txt`, etc, though the name in the window titles are "Untitled", "Untitled 2", etc (not congruent with filename). When you quit TextEdit and then restart, docs are reopened too.

Comment: Checking this setting is crucial for everyone who writes confidential data into a temporarily opened TextEdit window, which many may expect to reside in RAM only, but in reality gets persisted to iCloud immediately!

—

This default setting may be good for usability & convenience, but is very bad for security (save something seemingly ephemer like a fresh unsaved document straight to the cloud!).

Answer (score 10):

You can run the following Terminal command, which will revert the new behaviour of saving new files to iCloud:

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false
```

To set this for all apps, run…

```
defaults write -g NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false
```

<sup>To revert, replace `false` with `true`.</sup>

Comment: ❌ Doesn't work anymore on macOS 11 Big Sur:

`$ defaults read NSGlobalDomain "NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud" → The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud) does not exist`

✅ The other [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207151/11510) worked!